# Since updating to Xcode 13 I get a codsign error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-signing

After updating to Xcode 13.x on Monterey, I've started getting numerous Code sign error(s): `Command usr/bin/codesign failed with a nonzero exit code` when building my project.

Cleaning Build Folder and deleting derived data are NOT working as a fix. Any suggestions?

[image: error verbatim in Xcode 13.1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to delete the Apple Worldwide Certificate in my Keychain Access. It seems to recreate when building and fixes the codesign error. Sometimes there are [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxzSR.png) certificates and I just delete the older one:

[image: WWDRC certs]

[image: deleting older certificate]

Comment: Hello, do you have an idea, why this Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority keeps adding automatically? I removed it and I was able to compile several times. Then it stopped working after a while with the same error. So I looked into keychain and found that it was there once again. Next removal resolved the issue again.

Comment: I noticed that there were three (3) "Apple worldwide developer relations" CAs. Two for login and one for System. I deleted the older one for login and I was able to compile again....for a few times before the same error returned. No new "login" CA cert reappears. The System one is still there. I have also set their trust to "Always Trust" with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

For me, xcode13.4 / monterey osx, iOS 15.0 device. I recently upgraded to monterey and for some reason was the certificate not trusted in the keychain. I had to manually trust the keychain and then it worked. See this also. https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/change-the-trust-settings-of-a-certificate-kyca11871/mac